# OnCollisionEnter2D and OnTriggerEnter2D not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D camera follow script where if the player enters a collider it will test if that has the layer "waypoint" and if so the camera will go to the center of the gameobject with that collider in a smooth transition; however, when I try to test if the player is colliding with OnCollisionEnter2D it doesn't execute, I also tried OnTriggerEnter2D and that doesn't work either. I tested each with "is trigger" true, and false, and with a rigidbody set to kinematic. the only thing I haven't tried is adding a rigidbody with kinematic false, but I don't want to go through the trouble of having to make physics not effect the player with kinematic true.
Camera script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;

    public Transform playerFrame;

    public List<GameObject> waypoints;

    private bool hasWaypoints;
    private bool inWaypoint;
    private int waypointIn;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        hasWaypoints = true;

        if (waypoints.Count == 0)
        {
            hasWaypoints = false;
        }

        inWaypoint = false;
        waypointIn = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (hasWaypoints)
        {
            if (inWaypoint)
                Move(waypoints[waypointIn].transform.position);
            else
                MoveInFrame(player.position);
        }
        else
        {
            MoveInFrame(player.position);
        }
    }

    void MoveInFrame(Vector3 moveTo)
    {
        Vector3 playerFrameRelative = playerFrame.position - transform.position;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveTo - playerFrameRelative, 10);
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -10);
    }

    void Move(Vector3 moveTo)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveTo, 10);
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -10);
    }

    public void Coll(Collider2D collision)
    {        
        inWaypoint = true;
        waypointIn = waypoints.IndexOf(collision.gameObject);        
    }

    public void setWaypoint(bool b)
    {
        inWaypoint = b;
    }
}
```

Player script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 9.53f;
    public float jumpPower = 2.46f;
    public float gravity = 0.65f;
    public bool startsBackwards;
    public GameObject camera;
    public LayerMask layerMask;

    private float upSpeed;
    private int jumps;
    private RaycastHit2D hit;
    private Vector3 direction;

    void Start()
    {
        if (startsBackwards)
            direction = Vector3.left;
        else
            direction = Vector3.right;
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (jumps < 3)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("w") || Input.GetKeyDown("up") || Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
            {
                upSpeed = jumpPower + gravity;
                jumps--;
            }
        }

        transform.Translate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        upSpeed = upSpeed - gravity;
        if (upSpeed < 0)
        {
            hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, new Vector2(1, 1), 0, Vector2.down, -upSpeed, layerMask.value);
            if (hit)
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.down * hit.distance);
                jumps = 0;
                upSpeed = 0;
            }
            else
                transform.Translate(Vector3.up * upSpeed);
        }
        if (upSpeed > 0)
        {
            //hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, new Vector2(1, 1), 0, Vector2.up, upSpeed);
            if (false)
                transform.Translate(Vector3.up * hit.distance);
            else
                transform.Translate(Vector3.up * upSpeed);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Reverse")
        {
            if (direction == Vector3.right)
                direction = Vector3.left;
            else
                direction = Vector3.right;
        }

        if (camera.GetComponent<CamFollow>().waypoints.Contains(collision.gameObject))
            camera.GetComponent<CamFollow>().Coll(collision);
        else
            camera.GetComponent<CamFollow>().setWaypoint(false);
        Debug.Log("worked!");
    }
}
```

Help me please!!

Comment: Do you objects have Collider2D components? And do they have `Rigidbody2D` components? And is one of them `isTrigger`?

Comment: I have tested that and it didn't work, do you want me to screenshot my inspector window?

Comment: oh wait I just turned of "is trigger" for one of them (I had both of them set to "is trigger") and it worked, I wonder why this is a common problem.

Comment: Oh another point is as soon as there is any `Rigidbody2D` involved (there had to be otherwise you wouldn't get any collision anyway) you do **not** want to move your objects via the `Transform` component as this destroyes the physics and collision detection! Rather use e.g. `Rigidbody2D.MovePosition` etc

Comment: oop, wait I just broke it again, apperently I didn't have it saved but the one that I saved before was correct, I made a change to the code to get rid of the "debug.log" and saved it and now its broken again. I tried ctrl+z and it still is broken. lol.

Comment: is there a way to do it without a rigidbody?

Comment: If you look at the [Colliders -> Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) you will find that at least one `Rigidbody`/`Rigidbody2D` is always required otherwise there will be no collision detection

Comment: I think i will just delete the code and restart (probably watch a brackeys tutorial about it). thanks for your help!